# How to convert the String value into json?

Tags: java, json

I have a string of values separated by comma and "=". I need to convert this into proper json format:

```
value = value.replace("=", ":");
String [] arrayStr=value.split(",");

JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
String key = null;
for (String s: arrayStr){
    if(key == null) {
        key = s;
    } else {
        builder.add(key, s);
        key = null;
    }
}
JsonObject val = builder.build();
```

Here is the content that I have and how I would like to conert it:

```
[{Locale=en, Address={House=138, Street=Whitefield Road, CityDistrict=Bangalore, City=Bangalore, District=Bangalore, RegionCode=KA, Region=Whitefield, CountryCode=IND, Country=India, PostalCode=560066}}, {Locale=de, Address={House=138, Street=Whitefield Road, CityDistrict=Bangalore, City=Bangalore, District=Bangalore, RegionCode=KA, Region=Whitefield, CountryCode=IND, Country=India, PostalCode=560066}}]

[{"Locale":"en","Address":{"House":"138","Street":"Whitefield Road","CityDistrict":"Bangalore","City":"Bangalore","District":"Bangalore","RegionCode":"KA","Region":"Whitefield","CountryCode":"IND","Country":"India","PostalCode":"560066"}},{"Locale":"de","Address":{"House":"138","Street":"Whitefield Road","CityDistrict":"Bangalore","City":"Bangalore","District":"Bangalore","RegionCode":"KA","Region":"Whitefield","CountryCode":"IND","Country":"India","PostalCode":"560066"}}]
```

Comment: maybe JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse); ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.jooq.tools.json.ParseException: Unexpected character (L) at position 2.
 at org.jooq.tools.json.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:609)
 at org.jooq.tools.json.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:263)
 at org.jooq.tools.json.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:112)
 at org.jooq.tools.json.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
 at org.jooq.tools.json.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:69)

Comment: You're not showing the whole code. The problem is in the code you decided to not show.

Comment: The only thing missing from the above code is
String value = "[{Locale=en, Address={House=138, Street=Whitefield Road, CityDistrict=Bangalore, City=Bangalore, District=Bangalore, RegionCode=KA, Region=Whitefield, CountryCode=IND, Country=India, PostalCode=560066}}, {Locale=de, Address={House=138, Street=Whitefield Road, CityDistrict=Bangalore, City=Bangalore, District=Bangalore, RegionCode=KA, Region=Whitefield, CountryCode=IND, Country=India, PostalCode=560066}}]
";

Comment: The only thing missing from the above code is
String value = "[{Locale=en, Address={House=138, Street=Whitefield Road, CityDistrict=Bangalore, City=Bangalore, District=Bangalore, RegionCode=KA, Region=Whitefield, CountryCode=IND, Country=India, PostalCode=560066}}, {Locale=de, Address={House=138, Street=Whitefield Road, CityDistrict=Bangalore, City=Bangalore, District=Bangalore, RegionCode=KA, Region=Whitefield, CountryCode=IND, Country=India, PostalCode=560066}}]
";

Comment: Just debug and look what you add to the builder as keys. The first key is "[{Locale:en". I'm not sure if that is a valid key. The error message indicates it is not.

Comment: @mayamar is correct. You don't handle correctly the array and nested objects. Maybe if your input has a very specific format, you could transform it with regex to get the desired output. Otherwise you have to take spacial care for arrays [] and objects {}. Keys and values shouldn't contain these characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String value = arrayObject.get(VALUE).toString(); 
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(value);
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain what the `arrayObject` is?